# Implementing Google Maps JavaScript API without HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to develop an app that must be a JavaScript file to be read on the software the app is supposed to run on. I was wondering if there is a way to implement google maps on my UI without needing to use html file and only a Javascript file.

My current approach is creating a UI with the DOM function. Although it is not the best approach since DOM functions are generally used to manipulate existing objects, it is what I am limited to. I tried to create script files with commands such as script = document.createElement("script") and document.script.textContent = "stuff", but I get issues with asynchrony. The "stuff" I am putting in is based on the items between the script tags here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Is there any other way to implement google maps with solely JavaScript?

Comment: "the software the app is supposed to run on" - what kind of software is this? Is it something other than a website? The free Google JavaScript Maps API is only licensed for use on websites that are available to the general public at no charge. If it is a free public website and the only issue is that you need to load the API and create your elements in JavaScript without adding them to the HTML source, use the [asynchronous loading](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async) that the Maps API offers.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 things going on with a simple google maps, 
1) load the library,
2) javascript for initializing,
3) HTML code for the frame,
4) CSS for styling.

It is easy to accomplish the 2-4, just use `document.body.innerHTML=""` would solve the problem. For 1, we can use `document.body.appendChild(script);` to load the library in.

Here is a Jsfiddle where the Google Maps is implemented without HTML document.
http://jsfiddle.net/effd4fxa/

Hope it helps